# CMake transitive dependency is not found via find_package()

Tags: cmake

I have static library `Foo`, static library `Bar` that depends on `Foo` and executable `Baz` that depends on `Bar`.

Relevant sections from `Foo` `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
# Specifying files to copy during "make install" command.
install(TARGETS Foo EXPORT FooConfig
    INCLUDES DESTINATION include
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib)

# Specifying config file that will be used to find a library using find_package().
install(EXPORT FooConfig
    FILE FooConfig.cmake
    NAMESPACE Foo::
    DESTINATION lib/cmake/Foo)
export(TARGETS Foo
    NAMESPACE Foo::
    FILE FooConfig.cmake)
```

Relevant sections from `Bar` `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
# Specifying libraries that are required for build.
find_package(Foo REQUIRED)

# Specifying libraries to link to for the users of the library.
target_link_libraries(Bar PUBLIC Foo::Foo)

# Specifying files to copy during "make install" command.
install(TARGETS Bar EXPORT BarConfig
    INCLUDES DESTINATION include
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib)

# Specifying config file that will be used to find a library using find_package().
install(EXPORT BarConfig
    FILE BarConfig.cmake
    NAMESPACE Bar::
    DESTINATION lib/cmake/Bar)
export(TARGETS Bar
    NAMESPACE Bar::
    FILE BarConfig.cmake)
```

And finally `Baz` `CmakeLists.txt`:

```
find_package(Bar REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(Baz PRIVATE Bar::Bar)
```

Now when building `Baz` I get:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (add_executable):
  Target "Baz" links to target "Foo::Foo" but the
  target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an
  IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
```

So build finds `Bar` and correctly determines that it depends on `Foo` but can't find `Foo`. I have another test project that directly depends on `Foo` and it builds fine. How to fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, `BarConfig.cmake` generated like this does not handle finding dependencies, I had to modify `Bar` `CMakeLists.txt` to this:

```
# Specifying files to copy during "make install" command.
install(TARGETS Bar EXPORT BarTargets
    INCLUDES DESTINATION include
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib)
install(FILES CMake/BarConfig.cmake DESTINATION lib/cmake/Bar)

# Specifying config file that will be used to find a library using find_package().
install(EXPORT BarTargets
    FILE BarTargets.cmake
    NAMESPACE Bar::
    DESTINATION lib/cmake/Bar)
export(TARGETS Bar
    NAMESPACE Bar::
    FILE BarTargets.cmake)
```

Then I created a file `CMake/BarConfig.cmake` with this:

```
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/BarTargets.cmake")

find_package(Foo REQUIRED)
```

Now this `BarConfig.cmake` gets installed globally and calls `find_package` that finds `Foo`.

Comment: Great self-answer! The comments are a bit confusing: The first one appears to only apply to `BarConfig.cmake`, not `BarTargets.cmake`, but applies to both; the second one appears to only apply to `BarTargets.cmake`, not `BarConfig.cmake`, but it's actually the other way round.

Comment: Instead of `find_package()` rather `find_dependency()` should be used, this properly forwards the `QUIET` and `REQUIRED` keywords. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50277897/3519749) for details. Don't forget to `include(CMakeFindDependencyMacro)`.