# Difference between find_dependency and find_package in cmake?

Tags: cmake

In package-Config.cmake, if I do find_package instead of find_dependency, what would be the effect on my application? In what scenarios it will break?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakeFindDependencyMacro.html), `find_dependency` is just a wrapper around `find_package`:

> It is designed to be used in a Package Configuration File (`<package>Config.cmake`). `find_dependency` forwards the correct parameters for *QUIET* and *REQUIRED* which were passed to the original `find_package()` call. Any additional arguments specified are forwarded to `find_package()`.
>
> If the dependency could not be found it sets an informative diagnostic message and calls `return()` to end processing of the calling package configuration file and return to the `find_package()` command that loaded it.

If you would use, e.g., `find_package(REQUIRED)` instead of `find_dependency`, and the package won't be found, then it will be difficult for user to understand, that the error is related with outer package, not only with the inner one. Also, if outer call of `find_package` doesn't use *REQUIRE* option, it is inconsistent to perform inner call with that option.